# Looping through array and input value into field

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have a general question about a script to automate value inputs & clicking. The purpose is to select a site in the sites variable/concat into ns1 - ns2, click id add_gridVanity place the values into the input field and submit/close then repeat the process until the end of the array. I can't seem to get the for loop running. Sorry for the basic question.

```
sites = ["stonegrillla.com","schoolfoodbloomingroll.com","chapmanpizzeria.net","sushimasu.com","hmsbountyla.com","pailinthaicuisine.net","fullhouseseafood.com","cjssgourmetdelicatessen.com","bullsheadexpress.net","breakingbreadsf.net","lscaffe.net","latortagorda.org","pinecrestdiner.net","sunriserestaurant.net","tressf.net","hanazensf.com","piperade.org","mazzatsf.net","gaylordindia.net","thegrovefillmore.com","itstopscoffeeshop.net"]


for (i=0; i<sites.length; i++){

var base = 'ns1,ns2.';
var full = base.concat(sites[i]);
var sub1 = "ns1.".concat(sites[i]);
var sub2 = "ns2.".concat(sites[i]);
var both = sub1+'\n'+sub2;
$("#add_gridVanity").click();
$("#name").val(full);
$("#servers").val(both);
$("#sData").click();
$("#cData").click();
 console.log(sites[i]); //test
};
```

Comment: why do you have a semicolon (;) after ending the For ?

Comment: for your `both` you could reduce that to. `"ns1."+sites[i]+"\n"+"ns2."+sites[i]`. Try `var i = 0` instead of `i = 0`

Comment: you should be using block scope here

Comment: what do all the click handlers do? Likely a more efficient way to do whatever you are doing

Answer (score 1):

Few basic stuff, you need to declare variables and add semicolons. Just declared `sites` and `i` and semicolon after sites. The tricky part about javascript is even with one small error with syntax or comma or semicolon etc, entire thing would fail and you wouldn't realize the same, since it might be very silly. Use dev tools in browser to check errors

```
  var sites = ["stonegrillla.com","schoolfoodbloomingroll.com","chapmanpizzeria.net","sushimasu.com","hmsbountyla.com","pailinthaicuisine.net","fullhouseseafood.com","cjssgourmetdelicatessen.com","bullsheadexpress.net","breakingbreadsf.net","lscaffe.net","latortagorda.org","pinecrestdiner.net","sunriserestaurant.net","tressf.net","hanazensf.com","piperade.org","mazzatsf.net","gaylordindia.net","thegrovefillmore.com","itstopscoffeeshop.net"];


for (var i=0; i<sites.length; i++){

var base = 'ns1,ns2.';
var full = base.concat(sites[i]);
var sub1 = "ns1.".concat(sites[i]);
var sub2 = "ns2.".concat(sites[i]);
var both = sub1+'\n'+sub2;
$("#add_gridVanity").click();
$("#name").val(full);
$("#servers").val(both);
$("#sData").click();
$("#cData").click();
 console.log(sites[i]); //test
}
```

Above answer is only for *I can't seem to get the for loop running*. Once you have the loop running i think you should be able to figure out the rest

Comment: the for-loop just executes sites[0] and stops attempting to continue through out the array. I'd tried using checking for errors but console.log displays the whole loop without the click/val method.

Comment: I dont really have the html content, so I just wrote a working script fot you to see the `for` loop: http://jsfiddle.net/bpsfnzxd/1/